# Is it possible to mock os.scandir and its attributes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking, attributes

```
for entry in os.scandir(document_dir)
    if os.path.isdir(entry):
    # some code goes here
    else:
        # else the file needs to be in a folder
        file_path = entry.path.replace(os.sep, '/')
```

I am having trouble mocking os.scandir and the path attribute within the else statement. I am not able to mock the mock object's property I created in my unit tests.

```
with patch("os.scandir") as mock_scandir:
    # mock_scandir.return_value = ["docs.json", ]
    # mock_scandir.side_effect = ["docs.json", ]
    # mock_scandir.return_value.path = PropertyMock(return_value="docs.json")
```

These are all the options I've tried. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you realy need to mock. The problem is that `os.scandir` returns entries of type `os.DirEntry`. One possibility is to use your own mock `DirEntry` and implement only the methods that you need (in your example, only `path`). For your example, you also have to mock `os.path.isdir`. Here is a self-contained example for how you can do this:

```py
import os
from unittest.mock import patch


def get_paths(document_dir):
    # example function containing your code
    paths = []
    for entry in os.scandir(document_dir):
        if os.path.isdir(entry):
            pass
        else:
            # else the file needs to be in a folder
            file_path = entry.path.replace(os.sep, '/')
            paths.append(file_path)
    return paths


class DirEntry:
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path = path

    def path(self):
        return self.path


@patch("os.scandir")
@patch("os.path.isdir")
def test_sut(mock_isdir, mock_scandir):
    mock_isdir.return_value = False
    mock_scandir.return_value = [DirEntry("docs.json")]
    assert get_paths("anydir") == ["docs.json"]
```

Depending on your actual code, you may have to do more.

If you want to patch more file system functions, you may consider to use [pyfakefs](https://pypi.org/project/pyfakefs) instead, which patches the whole file system. This will be overkill for a single test, but can be handy for a test suite relying on file system functions.

*Disclaimer:* I'm a contributor to pyfakefs.